# Problem in a Taylor expansion of Runge-Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion, runge-kutta-methods

I'm stuck with this problem:

> Determine all three-stage, thre-order RK methods

I'm reading some papers about this and they do:

$$ y_{i} = y_{i-1} + \sum_{i=0}^m b_{j}k_{j} $$

$$
\begin{cases}
k_{1} = hf(t_{i-1},y_{i-1}) \\
k_{2} = hf(t_{i-1}+c_{2}h,y_{i-1}+a_{21}k_{1}) \\
k_{3} = hf(t_{i-1}+c_{3}h,y_{i-1}+a_{31}k_{1}++a_{32}k_{2}) \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now, they do a third order Taylor expansion of $y(t;t_{i-1},y_{i-1})$. The point is here:

$$
y_{i} = y_{i-1} 
 + f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})h 
 + \cfrac{1}{2}\left[  \frac{\partial }{\partial t}  f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1}) 
    + f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1}) \frac{\partial }{\partial y}  f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})  \right]h^2
 + ... 
$$

I'm trying to get this expression but I don't know to do it:

$$
\frac {d}{dh} f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1}) 
= \frac {\partial }{\partial t} f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})\frac {dt}{dh}
+ \frac {\partial }{\partial y} f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})\frac {dy}{dh}
$$

So that, it means that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac {dt}{dh} = 1 \\
\frac {dy}{dh} = f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1}) \\
\end{cases}
$$

But I don't understand it (in case this is right).

Please, anyone could help me to understand it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957088/a-question-regarding-runge-kutta-method-of-order-3/3958591#3958591

Comment: It makes no sense to differentiate by $h$ here. The symbol $h$ is actually just shorthand for $t_i - t_{i-1}.$ Differentiate by $t$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the derivative $\frac{dy}{dh}$, you are considering the function $h\mapsto y(t_{i-1}+h)$ for an exact solution of the ODE with initial condition $y(t_{i-1})=y_{i-1}$. In consequence you get indeed
$$
\frac{dy}{dh}(t_{i-1})=y'(t_{i-1})=f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1}).
$$

Any ODE problem can be transformed into an autonomous first order system $u'(t)=F(u(t))$. In application this can then be reduced back to the non-autonomous case. In the autonomous case the propagation of the exact solution has the Taylor expansion
$$\begin{multline}
u(t+h)=u(t)+h·F(u(t))+\frac{h^2}2F'[F]+\frac{h^3}6\Bigl(F''[F,F]+F'[F'[F]]\Bigr)
\\+\frac{h^4}{24}\Bigl(F'''[F,F,F]+3F''[F'[F],F]+F'[F''[F,F]]+F'[F'[F'[F]]]\Bigr)+O(h^5)
\end{multline}$$
For the stages of the method one gets the expansions
$$\begin{align}
k_1&=hF\\
k_2&=hF+a_{21}h^2F'[F]+\tfrac12 a_{21}^2h^3 F''[F,F]+O(h^4)\\
k_3&=hF+hF'[a_{31}hF+a_{32}h(F+a_{21}hF'[F]]+\tfrac12hF''[a_{31}hF+a_{32}hF]^2+O(h^4)\\
&=hF + (a_{31}+a_{32})h^2F'[F] + a_{32}a_{21}h^3F'[F'[F]] + \tfrac12(a_{31}+a_{32})^2h^3F''[F,F]+O(h^4)
\end{align}$$
and assembled
$$\begin{multline}
u_{+1} = u+(b_1+b_2+b_3)hF+(b_2a_{21}+b_3(a_{31}+a_{32}))h^2F'[F] \\+ \tfrac12(b_2a_{21}^2+b_3(a_{31}+a_{32})^2)h^3F''[F,F] + b_3a_{32}a_{21}h^3F'[F'[F]] + O(h^4)
\end{multline}$$
Now using $a_{21}=c_2$ and $a_{31}+a_{32}=c_3$ and comparing both expansions gives the conditions
\begin{align}
\text{order $1$}&:& b_1+b_2+b_3&=1\\
\text{order $2$}&:&  b_2c_2+b_3c_3&=\tfrac12\\
\text{order $3$}&:&  b_2c_2^2+b_3c_3^2&=\tfrac13\\
 & &  b_3a_{32}c_2&=\tfrac16\\
\end{align}
See also [Butcher 2008: RK introduction](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ebutcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/RK-methods.pdf) and [low order methods](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ebutcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/low-order-RK.pdf) for a more systematic approach and examples of methods.