# Quadrature Formula and Interpolation

Tags: calculus, polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

Suppose we want to integrate a function from $x_0$ to $x_0 + 3h$, and we know the value of this function at $x_0$, $x_1 = x_0 + h$, and $x_2 = x_0 + 2h$. Write a quadrature formula to approximate the value of this integral.

So, what I did was interpolate the points with a polynomial P(x) and then calculate $\int _{x_0}^{x_0 + 3h} P(x)dx$ and had:
$$\int _{x_0}^{x_0 + 3h} P(x)dx = \int _{x_0}^{x_0 + 3h} \sum_{i=0}^2 {f_i}{l_i}(x) = f(x_0)\frac{3h}{4} + 0 + f(x_2)\frac{9h}{4} = \frac{3h}{4}[f(x_0)+3f(x_2)]$$

Is the process correct? I thought I had to get a Simpson's Rule 1/3 or 3/8.

Is there a way to test if the answer is correct by evaluating some random function? I tried $\int _{0}^{3} sin(x)dx $ and $\frac{3}{4}[sin(0)+3sin(2)]$ but don't know if that's it.

Comment: You can find this combination in the Heun-Ralston second-order and the 3rd order Heun (Runge-Kutta) method for integrating ODE. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3337299/among-midpoint-method-heuns-method-and-ralston-method, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345211/euler-vs-heun-numerical-methods.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to assume that,
since you know the value at
3 points, is to assume that
$P(x)=a+bx+cx^2$
and evaluate the integral
for $f(x)$ as a constant,
$f(x)=x$,
and
$f(x)=x^2$ so that
the integral of
$P(x)$
matches these results.